# Import *.ods file in MySQL without phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, mysqlimport, ods

I'm trying to import a *.ods file using mysqlimport or 'load data' instead of phpMyAdmin interface because I need to automate the process.
This is my first attempt:

```
mysqlimport --ignore-lines=1 -u root -p DATABASE /home/luca/Scrivania/lettura.ods
```

mysqlimport can't upload the file because there are two spreadsheets, I need both and I can't modify the file structure.

With phpMyAdmin i'm able to upload the file correctly. The content of the two spreadsheets fills correctly the two tables. I know that when importing an *.ods file like this, phpMyAdmin uses the sheet name as the table name for import the file, but this is not the behavior of mysqlimport. Mysqlimport uses the file name, not the sheet name.

So I've tried this:

```
mysql -u root -p -e "load data local infile '/home/luca/Scrivania/lettura.ods' into table TABLE_NAME" DATABASE
```

Returns no error but the data in the table is totaly inconsistent.

Any suggestions?
Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL doesn't know how to read spreadsheets. Your best bet is to use your spreadsheet program to export a CSV, then load that new CSV into the database. Specify comma-delimited loading in your query and try it:

```sql
LOAD LOCAL DATA INFILE '/home/luca/Scrivania/lettura.csv'
INTO TABLE TABLE_NAME
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '' ESCAPED BY '\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
STARTING BY ''
```

The [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html) for file loading contains tons of possible options, if you need them.

Comment: I set starting by '2' because I need to skip the first row. I got an error . I think  I'm misunderstanding what starting by means?

Comment: That option tells MySQL which symbol indicates the start of a line. It's blank by default, so you can probably omit it.